# Undefined offset: 5-6

Tags: php

I got an error in my php script. 
It's saying "Undefined offset: 5" and "Undefined offset: 6" on line 7.

```
class mooninfo{

    private function moon($second, $minute, $hour, $month, $day, $year){
        $lineinfo = @exec("perl ./cgi-bin/moon2.pl second=".$second." minute=".$minute." hour=".$hour." month=".$month." day=".$day." year=".$year);
        $arrayinfo = explode("|", $lineinfo);
        $arrayas = array("distance" => $arrayinfo[0],   "AgeOfMoon" => $arrayinfo[1], "K" => $arrayinfo[2], "nameimg" => $arrayinfo[3], "phaseDesc" => $arrayinfo[4], "moonPhase" => $arrayinfo[5], "phaseTime" => $arrayinfo[6]); //It's happening here
        return $arrayas;
    }


    public function info(){
        return "Info of class mooninfo";
    }

    public function getmoon($second, $minute, $hour, $month, $day, $year){
        return $this->moon($second, $minute, $hour, $month, $day, $year);
        //return $this->moon2();
    }
}
```

I defining it like this

```html
<?=$arrayinfo["phaseTime"]?>
```

Comment: it means there is no $arrayinfo[5] or higher

Comment: Where are you defining `$arrayinfo`?

Comment: better yet, the problem is probably in the code for 'cgi-bin/moon2.pl'

Answer (score 0):

An undefined offset error occurs when you're referencing an array key that does not exist. As Santy pointed out in the comments, there is no `$arrayinfo[5]` or higher.

What is actually causing the error is impossible to tell because it seems to start with the line

```
$lineinfo = @exec("perl ./cgi-bin/moon2.pl second=".$second." minute=".$minute." hour=".$hour." month=".$month." day=".$day." year=".$year);
```

You don't provide any information on what is happening here, but I would go over your `cgi-bin/moon2.pl` file for errors. Additionally, you should stop suppressing errors with the `@` operator as this defeats the purpose of debugging.